# Getting more on each iteration for list.append

Tags: python, list

I've written a code that lets the user continuously input new members' names for The Beatles, and prints a new list of members' names once the user has done with inputting, but I keep getting repeated names if I enter more than one name.

Could somebody help me out here?

```
# step 1
beatles = ['John Lennon', 'Paul McCartney', 'George Harrison']

new_list=[]
new_member = ''
while True:
    new_member = input ('Please enter new memebers to the group, enter NA to exit entering: ')
    if new_member == 'NA':
        break
    else:
        new_list.append (new_member)
        for i in new_list:
            beatles.append(i)
print("Step 3:", beatles)
```

Comment: Skip that `new_list` stuff, and directly append to `beatles`?

Comment: I could do that, but just want to know what is the problem with my current approach. Clearly there is something wrong and i want to figure it out

Comment: you're accumulating the inputs in `new_list` so you're adding the whole list at each iteration. Too complex. Simplify.

Comment: Even if you want `new_list` to track the new values, don't append everything inside it in each iteration to `beatles`, or you could simply add the `new_list` to `beatles` at the _end_ after user has given all the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two solution

1:

```
for i in new_list:
    if i not in beatles:
        beatles.append(i)
```

or you don't need new_list at all

2: after `else`

`beatles.append(new_member)`

Answer (score 0):

You should set new_member empty and define new_list each time the code runs you can make some changes as i done in you code and it will run while giving you the desired output.

```py
beatles = ['John Lennon', 'Paul_McCartney', 'Geogre Harrison']

while True:
    new_list=[]
    new_member = ''
   
    new_member = input ('Please enter new memebers to the group, enter NA to exit entering: ')
   
    if new_member == 'NA':
        break
    else:
        new_list.append (new_member)
    for i in new_list:
        beatles.append(i)
   
    print("Step 3:", beatles)
```